# Usage of INDIRECT excel function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I've got sheet with name `April 21` and other sheet with name `Summary`.

I'd like to prepare cell formula in `Summary` sheet that will refer to `April 21` sheet's cell `M10`. This works for me just fine, it displays valid value in `Summary` sheet cell:

```
='April 21'!$M$10
```

I try to generify this formula using `INDIRECT` formula, but it doesn't work at all

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $D$6 & " " & RIGHT($B$3;3;2) & "'!$M$10")
```

where `D6` contains month name and `B3` contains a concrete year, like 2021.

What is wrong with my formula?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  *After changing your `RIGHT` function to `RIGHT($B$3;2)`?*

Comment: Please show us a screenshot or demonstrate what is in cell `D6` and `B3`

Answer (score 0):

You doing wrong in `RIGHT()` function. Right function has only two parameter. So, it will be like `RIGHT($B$3,2)`. What you write is `MID()` function format. Try below formula.

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $D$6 & " " & RIGHT($B$3,2) & "'!$M$10")
```

Comment: Comma `(,)` and semicolon `(;)` depends on regional settings. Use semicolon in your case.

Comment: So it is just what I've got now. `RIGHT` works for me with `;` and also I can use function like `text fragment`

Comment: No, just your solution is as good as mine, which is not working.

Comment: I tested it and working here. I assume then you have different data in cell `D6` and `B3`. Can you check what is data type for these two cell. Year cell is number or date? `B3` cell is just text or date field?

Answer (score 0):

If the cell with the year is a date formatted cell then the value will be a float value you take right from.
If that is true then you can use year() to get the year from the date as a string and take right of the string to get 21.

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $D$6 & " " & RIGHT(YEAR($B$3);2) & "'!$M$10")
```

Comment: This solution is not working, I mean, I tried and it's got same disadvantage as my formula from question. If I use `=RIGHT($B$3)` in separate cell it'll display value 21, so it's fine.

Comment: Is any of your cells a date? Try and set the format of D6 and B3 to number and see what happens, does anyone display a large float value?

Comment: Your formula works fine when using text values in B3 and D6, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxy07.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWfrF.png

Answer (score 0):

If the value in Cell `D6` is a date value formatted as month name, then your original formula will not work, and you can try the following:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&TEXT($D$6;"mmmm")&" "&RIGHT(B3;2)&"'!M10")
```

[image: solution]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&TEXT($D$6,"mmmm")&" "&RIGHT(B3,2)&"'!M10")
```

Or with your regional settings this becomes:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&TEXT($D$6;"mmmm")&" "&RIGHT(B3;2)&"'!M10")
```

These assume:

- Your cell containing "April" is formatted as a date, showing only the month name; and
- Your cell containing "2021" is either a text string or a number.